# When does a covering map between boundaries extend to covering maps between interiors?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, manifolds-with-boundary

Given two smooth three-manifolds $(M,\partial M)$ and $(N,\partial N)$ with smooth boundary, if we know that there is a covering map $\Gamma:\partial M\to\partial N$, is there a simple criterion to check whether $\Gamma$ extends to a (possibly branched) covering map $\gamma:(M,\partial M)\to (N,\partial N)$? Perhaps a criterion on the induced maps between various homology groups?

Furthermore, if such an extension does exist, is it true that the natural homomorphism $\text{Deck}(M\to N)\to\text{Deck}(\partial M\to\partial N)$ between the respective groups of Deck transformations is surjective?

Comment: I imagine you'll want to think about branched covering maps separately from covering maps, I have a guess that you can pick a branch locus to extend $\Gamma$ to a branched covering map much more often than you can just extend $\Gamma$ to a covering map.

Comment: In this degree of generality, it's hard to tell. Do you have a specific example you are interested in?